# Primeiro input é ignorado pelo scanf

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main(){
  int i;
  char c;
 
  while (scanf("%c", &c) != EOF){
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      scanf("%c", &c);
      printf("%c %d\n", c, i);
    }
  }
 
  return 0;
}
```

Se eu colocar "test" como input nesse código, eu queria que saísse

t 0
e 1
s 2
t 3

Mas o que sai, na verdade, é isso

e 0
s 1
t 2

Porque o primeiro "t" nao ta aparecendo?

Comment: `while (scanf("%c", &c)` lê o primeiro caractere (no caso, o "t"), e no `for` vc começa a ler do segundo em diante

Comment: @hkotsubo nossa, faz muito sentido, era isso mesmo. Obrigado!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

é que está acontecendo é que vc esta tirando a primeira letra para **scanf** do **while**. Se sua intenção é fazer que o **while** pare quando alguém aperte **crtl+c**, então não precisa colocar ele ali.

Outra coisa é que seria mais recomendado vc suar vetor de char para esse tipo de coisa.

as mudanças que eu fiz foi para usar o vetor de char(string)

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main(){
  int i;
  char c[10];
 
  while (1){
    scanf("%s", &c);//fora do for para ler tudo de uma vez
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      if (c[i] == 0){ // verifica se foi gravado algo nesse espaço, caso contrario, saio do for
          printf("----------\n");
          break;
      }
      printf("c = %c i =%d\n", c[i], i); 
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```